# Expressing a vector in terms of an Arbitrary Vector?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, vectors

I've been working on vector questions and this one seems to have gotten me stuck.

I'm unsure on how to express $\mathbf v$ in terms of $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ such as:

$$(\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf i)\mathbf i + (\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf j)\mathbf j$$

Can somebody provide some help?

$$\mathbf v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} \ ; \ \mathbf i=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \ ; \ \mathbf j=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: $$ {v_1 \choose v_2} = {v_1 \choose 0} + {0 \choose v_2} = v_1 {1 \choose 0} + v_2 { 0 \choose 1} = v_1 \hat{i} + v_2 \hat{j}$$

Comment: @Simon S - Thank you but are you not missing out the i and j outside the brackets?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What I have written is correct. The other thing to point out that $v \cdot \hat{i} = {v_1 \choose v_2}\cdot {1 \choose 0} = v_1.1 + v_2.0 = v_1$. Similarly, $v \cdot \hat{j} = v_2$.

Comment: By the way, these vectors $i$ and $j$ are not "arbitrary vectors". They're the elements of the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That said, this decomposition of any $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$  **can** be done with two arbitrary non-orthogonal vectors

Comment: Of course $\mathbf v=(\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf i)\mathbf i + (\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf j)\mathbf j$, so there's $\mathbf v$ expressed (in some fashion) in terms of $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$. What is needed here is context to explain what exercise actually is to be performed here and what the difficulty was with it.